# Can't checkout directory from other branch with git

Tags: git

I have two branches, let's say `feature0` and `feature1`, and I'm on branch `feature0`. I want to checkout a directory `my_directory` from `feature1`, so I say

```
git checkout feature1 -- my_directory
```

what gives me the error

```
error: pathspec 'my_directory' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What is weird, because `my_directory` is under version control in both branches. Git version is 1.7.10.4.

Any idea?

Comment: that's weird. Are you sure about it? Show the output of the `git ls-tree feature1 .`

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind immediately is to check that you are in the right (top level or sub) directory within the repo.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. git definitely checks out the whole `my_directory` for me as this question is currently stated.

Comment: Thanks @kan, this helped. The reason was that some coworker changed the directory structure in feature1 and this is not immediately obvious when looking just at the file system. Still a lot to learn with git...